# Flash is not showing Errors/Stacktraces in debug player (firefox/chrome/whatnot)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, debugging

I am trying to debug application which fails on me silently online. I am a 100% certain that I am running the flash debug player. To even make sure I am not losing it, i throw an Error ON PURPOSE. But flash shows not a single stracktrace in the browsers. I am kind of close of losing it. Any clues ? I am trying this on chrome, and firefox. WTH? Compiling with FDT, debug mode, even set the compiler argument debug=true. This is normally not the case. I think my computer is going nuts or something.

Comment: Have you restarted FDT recently?  That's always my first reaction to unexplained behaviour.  As great a tool as it is, sometimes it does need rebooting.  Also, have you cleared your compiler to force a completely uncached build?

Comment: Check if you are using debug player: flash.system.Capabilities.isDebugger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you configured your debug player to log stuff to a file (see http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=logging_04.html)?

Since I did that I never see any stacktrace or other error message from the debug player in the browser, instead it goes to a log file (that I tail). At least I think it is since I set that up.

There is also an undocumented SuppressDebuggerExceptionDialogs setting that sound like it could give the behavior you describe. More info at http://www.senocular.com/?entry=475 and http://jpauclair.net/mm-cfg-secrets/

Comment: I had this same problem and found that `mm.cfg` did in fact have `SuppressDebuggerExceptionDialogs=1` in it.  I didn't change the config file.  I wonder what did.  Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 0):

You sure you're using debugger for non-IE browsers? Also if you're using chrome and you have multiple versions of the flash plugin installed you need to go to about:plugins then click the + tab on flash, and disable all flash plugins but the debugger version just to be sure.

http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Notice the activeX version and non-IE versions. Install both. Also if you have a beta version of flash installed, this will most likely override any stable debugger version installed. So either specify which plugin is to run in Chrome or remove all versions of flash player and install only the debugger version.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to triple check you are running a debug player in a browser :)

http://www.playerversion.com/

Answer (score 0):

Note that **there are four versions of Flash Player on Windows:**

- PPAPI *(comes with Chrome, used by default in Chrome)*
- NPAPI *(used by Firefox, Safari, Chrome-but-not-by-default)*
- ActiveX *(Used by IE in all versions of Windows except Windows 8)*
- ActiveX-In-Windows-8 *(Comes with IE11 only in Windows 8, updated automatically by Windows Update)*

All four of these require separate debug versions to be downloaded/installed.

---

Additionally, **versions of Flash prior to 11.5 didn't have stack traces in release builds.**  However, as of Flash 11.5, stack traces work in the release version of Flash.

However, that doesn't mean this is no longer an issue.  If your application is set to use a compiler older than 11.5 in `Flash Builder --> Project properties --> ActionScript Compiler`, you won't have stack traces.

Additionally, on that same page you can see your AIR SDK version.  If you're using v3.4 or older, you won't see stack traces.  If this is your issue, all your developers should update their AIR SDK by following the instructions [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/kb/overlay-air-sdk-flash-builder.html).