# Link in TextField of flash cannot be clicked if it is embedded in different domain

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, url, hyperlink, textfield

I wrote a flash (ActionScript3) based radio streaming player, there is a link in the player for users to click. It's is a "a" tag in TextField. The code looks like this

```
textField.htmlText = '<u><a href="' + url +'">' +  htmlEscape(text) + '</a></u>';
```

It works fine if I put my flash player in same domain of web-page, however, if the domain of web-page is different from the location of flash player, then the link is not clickable.

For example:

[A radio example page](http://now.in/radio/victor)

You can see there is a link in the title bar of radio player, I hosted the flash player on CDN, its domain is different from the web-page, therefore, the link is not clickable.

Why the link cannot be clicked if it is embedded in a cross-domain page? It doesn't make any sense. I did set the [crossdomain.xml](http://now.in/corssdomain.xml) file properly, but it appears that it doesn't work. How can I solve this? I want to make the link clickable everywhere, no matter what domain the web-page is located.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this error message when testing it:

> URL for window '_self' halted (AllowScriptAccess is 'sameDomain'):
>   http://now.in/radio/victor

So maybe it can be fixed by setting allowScriptAccess="always" in the embedding code in the page.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. By the way, where did you find the error message? I can't see any message when I am viewing the page.

Comment: I use the debug version of Flash Player, and have error logging set up as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871800/flash-is-not-showing-errors-stacktraces-in-debug-player-firefox-chrome-whatnot/6875539#6875539